# How to identify backing dataset name for elastic search service API through slate in Palantir Foundry?

Tags: palantir-foundry

trying to find backing dataset of elastic search service API through slate in palantir foundry. i need the dataset for implementing objects.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming by "elastic search service" you're referring to the Phonograph2 Service API in you Slate instance? In that case, you can write a new query choosing the **Table Registry Service** and the **Get Table Metadata** endpoint and pass in the Table RID. The response will have the Dataset RID, which you can paste into the Foundry search to find the dataset.

If you're using some custom ElasticSearch source as a Slate source, then you'll probably need help from your Palantir support team.